# how to properly do multiply accumulate with NEON intrinsics

Tags: c, arm, neon

i need to do a simple multiply accumulate of two signed 8 bit arrays.

This routine runs every millisecond on an ARM7 embedded device. I am trying to speed it up a bit. I have already tried optimizing and enabling vector ops.

-mtune=cortex-a15.cortex-a7 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -ftree-vectorize -ffast-math -mfloat-abi=hard

this helped but I am still running close to the edge.

this is the 'c' code.

```
for(i = 4095; i >= 0; --i)
{ 
  accum += arr1[i]*arr2[i];
}
```

I am trying to use NEON intrinsics. This loop runs ~5 times faster, but I get different results. I am pretty sure I am not properly retrieving the accumulation, or it rolls over before I do. Any help/pointers is greatly appreciated. Any detailed docs would also be helpful.

```
 for(int i = 256; i > 0; --i)
 {   
   int8x16_t vec16a = vld1q_s8(&arr1[index]);                                                                                                                  
   int8x16_t vec16b = vld1q_s8(&arr2[index]);
   vec16res = vmlaq_s8(vec16res, vec16a, vec16b);
   index+=16;
 }
```

EDIT to post solution.

Thanks to tips from all!
I dropped to to 8x8 and have a fast solution

using the below code I achieved a "fast enough" time. Not as fast as the 128bit version but good enough.

I added  __builtin_prefetch() for the data, and did a 10 pass avg.
Neon is substantially faster.

$ ./test 10
original code time ~ 30392nS
optimized C time   ~  8458nS
NEON elapsed time  ~  3199nS

```
  int32_t   sum    = 0;                                                                                                                                            
  int16x8_t vecSum = vdupq_n_s16(0);
  int8x8_t  vec8a;
  int8x8_t  vec8b;
  int32x4_t sum32x4;
  int32x2_t sum32x2;

#pragma unroll
  for (i = 512; i > 0; --i)
  {
    vec8a  = vld1_s8(&A[index]);
    vec8b  = vld1_s8(&B[index]);
    vecSum = vmlal_s8(vecSum,vec8a,vec8b);
    index += 8;
  }

  sum32x4 = vaddl_s16(vget_high_s16(vecSum),vget_low_s16(vecSum));
  sum32x2 = vadd_s32(vget_high_s32(sum32x4),vget_low_s32(sum32x4));
  sum    += vget_lane_s32(vpadd_s32(sum32x2,sum32x2),0);
```

Comment: do you `-O3` or `-O2`? try pragma unroll and I guess that your code will faster than neon one

Comment: have tried all levels of opt -O2 thru -O4 and pragma unroll. NEON is still the fastest, but not very useful when it's wrong :) also tried *(arr1+i) * *(arr2+i) just in case the indexing made a diff.

Comment: Maybe go from the other direction.  Look at the assembly generated by the naive C code, and see whether it is noticeably suboptimal or if you could imagine something better.

Comment: If you want to do this handling all values, then yes, overflow is the problem.  You have to use the widening "long multiply" `vmull` or similar, to get 16-bit results from your multiplication (needing 2 vectors to hold them).  Then you have to widen again, because the accumulator has to be 32 bits, so I think that's `vaddw_s16`, and you need 4 vectors to hold those 16 accumulators.    You may very well end up finding that this is exactly what gcc's version is doing.

Comment: a [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/bfY11n4f7) - note that I've added `-mcpu` and made some assumptions (e.g. type of `accum`)

Comment: `aarch32` or `aarch64`?Is the array length fixed 4096? What's the data type of `accum`? `int32_t`? Of course neon result is incorrect due to the almost guaranteed overflows. Be more specific on data type, size, and target architecture when asking questions.

Comment: Now I see it's `ARMv7` (`aarch32`) `ARM7` is `ARMv4`

Comment: If you want a proper answer on doing something properly, ask properly first. How about starting properly with changing your nick from user###########??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely overflow, so you'll need to lengthen when you do your multiply-accumulate.
As you're on ARMv7, you'll want [vmlal_s8](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=%5BNeon%5D&f:@navigationhierarchiesarchitectures=%5Bv7%5D&q=vmlal_s8).
ARMv8 A64 has [vmlal_high_s8](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=%5BNeon%5D&q=vmlal) which allows you to stay in 128-bit vectors, which will give an added speed-up.

As mentioned in comments, seeing what auto-vectorization will do with -O options / pragma unroll is very valuable, and learning from the godbolt of that. Unrolling often gives speed-ups when doing by hand as well.

Lots more valuable tips on optimization in the [Arm Neon resources](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.arm.com/Architectures/Neon&sa=D&source=docs&ust=1662653315159239&usg=AOvVaw3vNHeGdmdkXFKaScZ45y-E).

Comment: auto-vectorization is very very unlikely and useless in this case since the values go through the long model twice. `vmlal.s8` isn't very useful either. It has to be `vmull.s8` followed by `vpadal.s16`. I would have already written an answer if OP had answered my questions or his name wasn't `user######`

Comment: sorry @Jake'Alquimista'LEE I was sleeping when you posted. I did change my name. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Intrinsics are probably the way. But you can also improve the gcc codegen by writing a "normal" `for` loop (counting up instead of down). This gets rid of the pointless shuffle in the hot path. (Though still no multiply-accumulate.)